# Use java methods as scala function

Tags: java, scala

Can you do something like this were Java is a java library

```
class TryStuff(method:() => Any) {
   private val lib: Java = new Java

   val tryStuff:TryStuff = new TryStuff(lib.method)
}
```

Is there someway to convert lib.method to a scala object

Comment: What do you mean by library? Package? I don't see anything problematic in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val tryStuff:TryStuff = new TryStuff(x => lib.method(x))
```

or more concisely

```
val tryStuff:TryStuff = new TryStuff(lib.method _)
```

Comment: or more concisely: `val tryStuff = new TryStuff(lib.method _)`

Comment: It does not compile. The 'method' function passed in the TryStuff constructor does not take parameter.

Comment: It was just an example, the original code did not compile either.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do anything special. Java methods are ready to be invoked in the Scala code.

In your example any method that does not have parameters can be used, in this case I use the method exists() of class java.io.File:

```
import java.io.File

class TryStuff(method:() => Any) {
    private val lib: File = new File("a.file")
    val tryStuff:TryStuff = new TryStuff(lib.exists)
}
```